# Can someone help me with this first order linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let s,T be fixed, and let $\phi(t):=\mathbb{E}[H_T-H_s|\mathcal{H}_{s,T}]$ which solves the following first order differential equation:

$\phi(t) = \int^t_s \frac{dv}{T-v}(H_T-H_s)$$-\int^t_s\frac{dv}{T-v}\phi(v)$ ;$s\leq t\leq T$

We know that the boundary is $\phi(s)=0$.

I would like to show that $\phi(t)=\frac{H_T-H_s}{T-s}(t-s)$.

The question is taken from the paper [Harnesses, Levy bridges and Monsieur Jourdain](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406563) by Roger Mansuy and Marc Yor pg 5.